copy cmd in windows 10 environment command prompt
Is there a copy command in Win 10 Command Prompt that will allow you to copy and rename a file in a subfolder back to the same subfolder?
I have 6000 subfolders all with a .jpg file that I want to copy back to the same folder and rename it to another filename.

It's unlikely there is a single command that will do what your trying to do. Is it a single jpg file in each folder? Creating batch script or powershell script to do what you want shouldn't be too hard.

Yes, a single jpg file in each folder, but each folder has a different jpg in it.

I've never played in Power Shell. Is there a command in PS for this?

There are many different ways to accomplish this, using a variety of commands strung together in a script. However, this site is not a script writing service. You need to approach this problem by breaking it into its component parts, which you've actually already articulated: Find, Rename, Move (or copy). So, begin doing your research regarding how to find the files you need to find, then how to rename those files, and finally, how to move them. Begin working towards that solution and, as you encounter problems, bring those specific problems  here and we might be able to help.
